# R: change all plots at once (ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a R document with several plots (ggplot2). Is there a way to change the settings for every plot with one line of code?
For example to change all colors, themes, x&y scales and formats?

I was thinking about a way to store all attributes in one variable and would add this to every plot so when I change the variable, all plots are changed.

I tried this:

```
mysettings <- labs(title=xy,...)+ theme_bw()+ geom_smooth(method='loess')+ ...
```

and then:

```
ggplot(..) + mysettings
```

but this did not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: `mysettings <- list(..., ..., ...)`